# How to create a handle DeepLink? To receive the link and open the specific page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, deep-linking

Open in the Browser and open the app like that

```
<NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
</NavigationContainer>
```

```
<DEEP_LINK_SCHEME>://info?page?id
```

Comment: You want to know how to handle navigation in your react-native app, is that right? So opening the app already works. Or is your question how to register the deep link scheme, so that it opens your app?

Comment: Register the deep link scheme